# Flutter web, How to close or dismiss indext.html after loading the app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I customized the `indext.html` file and I've added a loading and an image inside it, After loading the app, My `MaterialApp` comes up and covers the `indext.html` file (looks fine), but if I use a **transparent** Widget for my page, I can see the loading and image on `indext.html` below my material app!
As they are consuming resources, how can I stop my loading state on `indext.html` when app is loaded?

Comment: put a js script in index.html which unloads all the elements which are not needed

Comment: @Yadu, I'm not web developer, can you please provide a code snippet for that?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Yadu, I've achieved the solution:
First set id to `div`s that are going to hide (remove):

```
<div id="div1">
  ...
</div>
```

Then at the bottom of `index.html` file, modify the `script` that is provided by flutter like this:

```
<script>
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("flutter_service_worker.js");
          var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

          setTimeout(function() { 
            div1.remove(); 
          }, 7000); // remove div by delay to make sure flutter module is completely loaded
        });
      }
    </script>
```